# Can i get number of action count in a SharePoint Designer workflow in SPO --- Modernization script provide wrong data - Any SPO Powershell script?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

Can i get number of action count in a SharePoint Designer workflow in SPO
Modernization script output doesn't give us proper numbering
Any SharePoint Online PowerShell script??

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think there is such PowerShell command, since there doesn't seem to be property related to action counts.

See the document here: [WorkflowAssociation properties.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee536762(v=office.15))